# White screen after upgrading to angular@5.0.0

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I've upgraded angular from v4.4.6 to v5.0.0 and angular-cli from v1.3.2 to v1.5.0. The build is super fast (10sec compared to >1min) but nothing is working.

When I go to localhost:4200 all I get is a white screen, no errors, no warning.

I haven't upgraded any other package, I've tried downgrading angular-cli, the result is the same.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue ?

Comment: Did you follow this: https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/?

Comment: yes, checked all the boxes, still the same...